# Is there a way to refer to only some fields in a Django ForeignKey?

Tags: django, database, model, foreign-keys

I believe this is best explained by an example. So, I am making a program for saving weightlifting results for international and national competitions. Below is a (weight)lifter model:

```
class Lifter(Person):
    # Changed from dateTime, as we don't need time of birth
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Gender.choices(), 
    null=True)
    club = models.ForeignKey('Club', null=True)
```

I would like to connect the lifter model to the InterntionalResult model:

```
class InternationalResult(models.Model):

    lifter = models.ForeignKey(Lifter, null=True)

    body_weight = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Kroppsvekt', null=True)

    # International group can be (for example) "A" or "B"
    group = models.CharField(max_length=5, verbose_name='kategori')

    snatch = models.IntegerField()
    clean_and_jerk = models.IntegerField()
    total = models.IntegerField()
```

However, lifter has a ForeginKey to group (club = models.ForeignKey('Club', null=True)). When I connect Lifter to InternationalResult, I would like to exclude this ForgeinKey, but still connect Result to the rest of Lifter. This is because international competitions don't have clubs in the same way.

Is there a way to do this, or should I just create a new InternationalLifter-model?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your example doesn't really explain the question. What do you mean by "exclude" this ForeignKey? It's a field on the model, you can enter data for it or not depending on the validation rules of the model.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with it? Is this going to be displayed in a template? The easiest way to "exclude" a field is to just not render it, or not use it in general. Don't worry about performance, foreign-key relations are only fetched when you evaluate them.